# Only one post per day permission

Tags: python, django

So, I am pretty pure knowledge in DateTimeField data and I will be grateful for help. The task is to add users the ability to create only one post for a day. I have a date of last post and now I should check it with today date and get permission or not get.

How I can check is datetimefield data is today date?

so lets see in code. Something goes wrong:

```
class Board (models.Model):

    @property
    def pub_allowed(self):
       try:
           last_post_day = self.post_set.all()[self.post_set.count() - 1].created
           if last_post_day == utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today()):
                return False

           return True

       except Post.DoesNotExist:
           return True

class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField (max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField (max_length=120)
    created = models.DateTimeField (editable=False)
    board = models.ForeignKey (Board)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()

        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now always return True ((

Comment: get current datetime object `datetime.datetime.now()` and see if previous saved datetime value and current value lie on same date! provide access in that case

Comment: Check the equality of `toordinal()` or `(year, month, day)` of both date and datetime.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion:

```
created = models.DateTimeField (editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

with the [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) logic you can avoid writing your own custom `save()` method

Second:

```
last_post_day = self.post_set.all()[self.post_set.count() - 1].created
....
```

This will also check times, which is not what you want since you need to be in a completely different day. You could start by rewriting this as:

```
last_post_day = self.post_set.all()[-1].created.day
return last_post_day >= utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today()).day
```

This of course will not be perfect when you're changing month, but a bit of tweaking around to check only the `Date` value and not the `DateTime` is enough. Also, if you don't care about the time, you could directly convert `DateTimeField` to `DateField`, allowing you to just compare dates:

```
created = models.DateField (editable=False)
...
...
last_post_day = self.post_set.all()[-1]
return last_post_day >= datetime.date.today()
```